# How would I clean up old academics paper pdf files?

Tags: pdf, fonts

In my experience, old papers from academia quite often with "ugly OCRed" characters.

To describe this phenomenon better, one perfect example is the classic Donald Knuth paper : [https://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~mak/CS185C/KnuthStructuredProgrammingGoTo.pdf](https://www.cs.sjsu.edu/%7Emak/CS185C/KnuthStructuredProgrammingGoTo.pdf)

This pdf contains correct text (it's copy pastable and the pasted text seems correct), but in my opinion the characters font is terrible, and makes it a pain to read.

How would I go to transform this PDF to use a clean font instead of its current blurry characters ?

Comment: The OCR process doesn't make the characters ugly, it's that the document has been OCR'd from a scan that was done at too low a resolution to produce attractive characters. It's the low-rez scan that makes the ugly.  As @gettalong mentions, there's not much to be done, unless perhaps you wanted to copy/paste the text into a new word processing document and format to taste. That might introduce other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF looks like it was scanned and then character recognition was performed. What this means is that the characters you see are actually part of an image that fills the page and what you select are transparent characters layed above the image.

So there is no real way to completely preserve the appearance while making the font legible. Best shot would be finding a purely digital version of the paper(s).

Edit: In light of you comment I wrote a small script that performs the task you want:

```
require 'hexapdf'

# This processor changes the font color to black.
class ContentProcessor

  attr_reader :result

  def initialize
    @result = ''.b
    @serializer = HexaPDF::Serializer.new
  end

  TEXT_SHOW_OPERATORS = [:Tj, :"'", :'"', :TJ].each_with_object({}) {|op, h| h[op] = true }

  def process(op, operands)
    if TEXT_SHOW_OPERATORS[op]
      @result << HexaPDF::Content::Operator::DEFAULT_OPERATORS[:g].
        serialize(@serializer, 0)
      @result << HexaPDF::Content::Operator::DEFAULT_OPERATORS[:Tr].
        serialize(@serializer, 0)
    end
    if op != :Do
      @result << HexaPDF::Content::Operator::DEFAULT_OPERATORS[op].
        serialize(@serializer, *operands)
    end
  end

end

HexaPDF::Document.open(ARGV[0]) do |doc|
  doc.pages.each do |page|
    processor = ContentProcessor.new
    HexaPDF::Content::Parser.parse(page.contents, processor)
    page.contents = processor.result
    page[:Contents].set_filter(:FlateDecode)
  end
  doc.write(ARGV[1], validate: false)
end
```

This uses the [HexaPDF library](https://hexapdf.gettalong.org) under the hood (nb I'm the author of HexaPDF) and can be run like this: `ruby script.rb INPUT.PDF OUTPUT.PDF`.

I have run the script over your sample PDF and got the [this output](https://gist.github.com/gettalong/9423e6cdab93ec17a5f3aa44a531eeb2/raw/4631f46e933de706678df09e4c5d84aaf2a52c15/knuth.pdf). It is okay for most parts but there are definitely errors there.

Comment: Is there a way to make the image part invisble, and the invisible characters visible ? 
Edit : this answer put me on track of https://superuser.com/questions/178123/how-to-replaces-images-of-text-in-pdfs-with-formatted-text-using-ocr , so i'll accept it and dig from there ! 
Thanks for the explanation :-)

Comment: Yes, this is possible but the result may not look better because the kerning and other text layout stuff will not be completely correct.

Comment: I have edited my answer and included a small script that does what you want.

Comment: Whao, that's really impressive ! Thanks so much ! I started linking imagemagick, potrace and various other stuff, but couldn't get something remotely as good !

Comment: Also a note for a potential future reader : the script provided here gives a "true text" pdf format, meaning you can simply edit it with any program, (for example libreoffice draw) for a final polish.